# How to add barcode magento invoice?

Tags: php, magento, barcode, barcode-scanner, magento-1.8

I am new to magento. I need to add **barcode** on invoice. I am using magento CE 1.8.0.0. How can I add barcode to invoice?. I tried many extensions and no use.

Comment: can you share the links of the extensions that u have tried??

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/firegento-pdf.html

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/invoice-pdf-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

I have created POS scanning barcode in magento invoice. It's very simple and easy to customize for single product or invoice number.

**Edit :** app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

```
$fontPath = 'fonts/code39.TTF';                                
$barcodeImage = "*".$pro_sku."*";
$page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($fontPath), 36);

//Draw image to PDF
$page->drawText($barcodeImage, 400, 800);
```

POS easy to scan code39 fonts.